# Migrations fail when SQLite database file does not exist?

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-4

It seems that migrations (sort of) fail silently when the database file does not exist. The migration executes but no db file is created and I can run the migration again. (It never says "nothing to migrate") If I create a blank file then it works.

This is odd because I thought SQLite always created the db file if it was not found so I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I've done wrong. Maybe it's a permissions problem? But everything else is working so I don't know. I'm using Windows 7 and the project is in my

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've issued this bug against [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1810).

Hopefully future versions will give an error if the database doesn't exist, or automatically create one.

Comment: I just created an artisan script that creates one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz, would you share it? :)

Answer (score 16):

[User *blamh* suggested](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1810#issuecomment-23399299) to add the following snippet to `app/start/artisan.php` to automatically recreate the database when it doesn't exist, instead of throwing an exception.

```php
if (Config::get('database.default') === 'sqlite') {
    $path = Config::get('database.connections.sqlite.database');
    if (!file_exists($path) && is_dir(dirname($path))) {
        touch($path);
    }
}
```

With this, you can safely delete the SQLite database and then re-migrate and re-seed it, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated and more flexible solution from [Virtlinks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21841641/4907524)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SqliteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (DB::getDriverName() === 'sqlite') {
            $path = DB::getConfig('database');
            if (!file_exists($path) && is_dir(dirname($path))) {
                touch($path);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way to automatically create the database file, tested on Laravel 5.4.

This is the same as Gummibeer's answer except that I moved the logic to the `App\Console\Kernel` class (`app/Console/Kernel.php`), and the check will be performed only when running the `migrate` command.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface  $input
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface  $output
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle($input, $output = null)
    {
        $this->touchSQLiteDatabase($input);

        return parent::handle($input, $output);
    }

    protected function touchSQLiteDatabase($input)
    {
        $this->bootstrap();

        if (substr((string)$input, 0, 7) == 'migrate' && DB::getDriverName() === 'sqlite') {
            $path = DB::getConfig('database');

            if (!file_exists($path) && is_dir(dirname($path))) {
                touch($path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```