# Laravel forge git deploy script with SQlite

Tags: sqlite, laravel, forge

I have a problem with the install repository script. I have to use SQlite. In order to use SQlite with laravel the database must be created. The deploy script fails if there is no database there. But it is catch 22 because I don't want the database in version control as this causes errors with git. Is there a way to edit the deploy script or laravel to create the SQlite database on running the migration script?

I know I can do this manually with git and the artisan touch command but this defeats the point of the deploy script.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from this post.

[Migrations fail when SQLite database file does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872110/migrations-fail-when-sqlite-database-file-does-not-exist)

I put this in the databes config file at the top.

```
$path = database_path('database.sqlite');
if (!file_exists($path) && is_dir(dirname($path))) {
    touch($path);
}
```

I still think there is probably a better solution out there though.